# Stata - Multiple rotated plots on graph (including distributions on sides of axes)

Tags: data-visualization, matlab, stata

I would like to produce a single graph containing both: (1) a scatter plot (2) either histograms or kernel density functions of the Y and X variables to the left of the Y axis and below the X axis.

I found a graph that does this in MATLAB -- I would just like to produce something similar in Stata:

[image]

That graph was produced using [the following MATLAB code](http://www.mathworks.com/products/demos/statistics/copulademo.html):

```
n = 1000;
rho = .7;
Z = mvnrnd([0 0], [1 rho; rho 1], n);
U = normcdf(Z);
X = [gaminv(U(:,1),2,1) tinv(U(:,2),5)];

[n1,ctr1] = hist(X(:,1),20);
[n2,ctr2] = hist(X(:,2),20);
subplot(2,2,2); plot(X(:,1),X(:,2),'.'); axis([0 12 -8 8]); h1 = gca;
title('1000 Simulated Dependent t and Gamma Values');
xlabel('X1 ~ Gamma(2,1)'); ylabel('X2 ~ t(5)');
subplot(2,2,4); bar(ctr1,-n1,1); axis([0 12 -max(n1)*1.1 0]); axis('off'); h2 = gca;
subplot(2,2,1); barh(ctr2,-n2,1); axis([-max(n2)*1.1 0 -8 8]); axis('off'); h3 = gca;
set(h1,'Position',[0.35 0.35 0.55 0.55]);
set(h2,'Position',[.35 .1 .55 .15]);
set(h3,'Position',[.1 .35 .15 .55]);
colormap([.8 .8 1]);
```

UPDATE: The Stata13 manual entry for "graph combine" has precisely this example (http://www.stata.com/manuals13/g-2graphcombine.pdf). Here is the code:

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/lifeexp, clear
generate loggnp = log10(gnppc)
label var loggnp "Log base 10 of GNP per capita"
scatter lexp loggnp, ysca(alt) xsca(alt) xlabel(, grid gmax) fysize(25) saving(yx)
twoway histogram lexp, fraction xsca(alt reverse) horiz fxsize(25) saving(hy)
twoway histogram loggnp, fraction ysca(alt reverse) ylabel(,nogrid) xlabel(,grid gmax) saving(hx)
graph combine hy.gph yx.gph hx.gph, hole(3) imargin(0 0 0 0) graphregion(margin(l=22 r=22)) title("Life expectancy at birth vs. GNP per capita") note("Source: 1998 data from The World Bank Group")
```

Comment: How to do questions usually off topic, but this is admittedly mostly ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a better a way to do it, but this is my quick attempt to take up the challenge.

```
sysuse auto,clear
set obs 1000
twoway scatter mpg price, saving(sct,replace)   ///
xsc(r(0(5000)20000) off ) ysc(r(10(10)50) off)  ///
xti("") yti("") xlab(,nolab) ylab(,nolab)

kdensity mpg, n(1000) k(gauss) gen(x0 d0)
line x0 d0, xsc(rev off) ysc(alt) xlab(,nolab) xtick(,notick) saving(hist0, replace)
kdensity price, n(1000) k(gauss) gen(x1 d1)
line d1 x1, xsc(alt) ysc(rev off) ylab(,nolab) ytick(,notick) saving(hist1, replace)

graph combine hist0.gph sct.gph hist1.gph, cols(2) holes(3)
```

I'd also like to know if there are ways to improve on it. The codes are not very neat, and I had trouble properly aligning the line plot and the scatter plot without removing the ticks and labels of the scatter plot (`xcommon` and `ycommon` did not really do the job for me).

credit to [this post](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2011-08/msg00027.html) on the Statalist.

Comment: Great attempt! This prompted me to look at the Stata manual's "graph combine" entry in more detail to see if I could shrink the kdensity graphs relative to the scatter plot. As it turns out, the Stata 13 manual has been updated with this very task (taken from a 2014 article by Lars Angquist). It's on pages 5-8 of the following link: http://www.stata.com/manuals13/g-2graphcombine.pdf

Comment: Interesting. So the examples in the manual basically answer your question. It'd be great if you could edit your post and include the solution for future references.